# Bootstrap time picker issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap time Picker control and store data in DB in string format like 6:30 PM. Now I have an issue when I edit the form and put that value in Bootstrap time Picker control, I got an issue, Any one can help in this regard.

String format is ="6:30 PM" and want to set that string in Bootstrap time Picker control.

EDIT:

I am filling in below format.

```
 blockHoursDetail.FillBlockHours(blockHoursDetail.params.BlockHoursId).done(function (response) {
            if (response.status != false) {
                var blockHours_detail = JSON.parse(response.BlockHoursFill_JSON);
                var self = $("#blockHoursDetail");
                utility.bindMyJSON(true, blockHours_detail, false, self);
                if (blockHours_detail.chkActive == 'True')
                    $("#blockHoursDetail #chkActive").attr("checked", true);
                else
                    $("#blockHoursDetail #chkActive").attr("checked", false);
                blockHoursDetail.ValidateBlockHours();
                $('#frmBlockHoursDetail').data('serialize', $('#frmBlockHoursDetail').serialize());
            }
            else {
                utility.DisplayMessages(response.Message, 3);
            }
        });
```

Comment: `$('#timepicker').timepicker('setTime', "6:30 PM");`

Comment: I m filling in below format   { "blockHoursFromTime", Utility.ToStr(Utility.ToDateTime(dr[dsSchedule.SchBlockHours.FromTimeColumn.ColumnName]))},

Answer (score 2):

When you return data from the db you should show it like that.

```
<?php echo date("h:i A",strtotime($time_from_db)); ?>
```

and if you are facing some problem in initializing of time picker the the specific format then you can use this

```
$('.timepicker').timepicker('setTime', "6:30 PM");
```

hope it will help you

Comment: I m filling in below format can you all anything  { "blockHoursFromTime", Utility.ToStr(Utility.ToDateTime(dr[dsSchedule.SchBlockHours.FromTimeColumn.ColumnName]))},

Comment: Could not get this can you further explain what do you want to ask?